# Kubernetes error during install

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I had these error during the installation of Kubernetes on AWS/Ubuntu.

```
 export  KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws && export AWS_S3_REGION=eu-west-1 && bash cluster/kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: aws
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Starting cluster using os distro: vivid
Uploading to Amazon S3
+++ Staging server tars to S3 Storage: lll-kube/devel
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument --region: expected one argument
```

Do you have any idea to fix that ?

## Update:

After setting up: `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1`

I typed:

```
$ :~/kubernetes# export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws && export AWS_S3_REGION=eu-west-1 && export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1 && export  AWS_S3_BUCKET=mybucket-xxxxx && bash cluster/kube-up.sh
```

The output:

```
... Starting cluster using provider: aws
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Starting cluster using os distro: vivid
Uploading to Amazon S3
Creating mybucket-xxxxx
make_bucket: s3://mybucket-xxxxx/

Unable to confirm bucket creation.
Please ensure that s3://mybucket-xxxxx exists
and run the script again. (sorry!)
```

I checked S3, the bucket was created. So I typed again the same command and the output was:

```
... Starting cluster using provider: aws
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Starting cluster using os distro: vivid
Uploading to Amazon S3
+++ Staging server tars to S3 Storage: mybucket-xxxxx/devel
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument --region: expected one argument
```

Comment: What s3 permissions are available to aws access key/iam profile?

Comment: I set up a public access to the bucket, I had always this error:
`+++ Staging server tars to S3 Storage: mybucket-xxxxx/devel

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]

aws: error: argument --region: expected one argument `

Answer (score 0):

Try setting AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable.